# Multiple private keys with RSA

Tags: encryption, rsa, public-key

Say I want generate pair of public/private keys. First of all lets choose two prime numbers $q = 17, p = 11$. Now, lets choose public key $e=7$ and try to determine the matching private key $d$:
$$d\cdot e \mod (q-1)(p-1) = 1$$
$$d\cdot 7 \mod 16\cdot 10 = 1$$
$$7d \mod 160 = 1$$

So, there are many solutions for this equation, such $23$, $183$, $343$ and in general $d = 160k+23$ for every $k\in Z$.

But RSA should have single private key for public key, so why can I get many solutions/private keys? I tested them, and they can decrypt the encryption of the public key $e$.

I know that $q$ and $p$ should be destroyed and without them it is hard to calculate the private key. I just don't understand why there are many private keys for one public key...

Comment: The key is unique in $[0,80]$ ie in $[0,\lambda(n)]$ where $\lambda(\cdot)$ is the [carmichael-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function) of the modulus. All of these keys are equivalent and given any of them you should be "easily" able to recover the others, this is a well-known fact. This implies that actually $103$ is a valid private key as well.

Comment: $d\cdot e \bmod (p-1)(q-1)\,=\,1$ is a sufficient condition for $d$ being a valid private exponent; this allows several values of integer $d$. The condition $d\cdot e \bmod \operatorname{lcm}(p-1,q-1)\,=\,1$ is a necessary and sufficient condition for $d$ being a valid private exponent, and allows even more values of integer $d$.

Comment: Anyone knowing *any* $e,d,N$ can calculate $p,q$ or $\lambda(N)$ in polynomial time. And then it's easy to calculate other representations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well,

1. You're working in the multiplicative group.
2. There is a theorem (which is proven by group axioms), that the inverse element is unique ($d$ is inverse to $e$).
3. When you say $d = 160 \cdot k + 23$ for every $k$ from $Z$, you actually should mean that in the context mod $160$ then your $d \cdot k$ for any $k$ is actually the same element.

I think the mindtrick here is that:

You claim: $d = 160 \cdot k + 23$ for every $k$ in Z; oh, there is a lot of such elements!
NO. You're in the multiplicative group. You can **write** this element different ways. But it is still the same element.

You do not work with "numbers". You work with **an element** of multiplicative group. Which can be represented many ways (see your claim about $k$). But it's the same element. In the context of 'multiplicative group mod $160$, elements $23$ and $183$ are the same elements.

You can easily prove that $23 \bmod 160 = 183 \bmod 160$. **So $183$ equals $23$ in group mod $160$**. That means you can write on sheet of paper $183$ or $23$ or whatever $160 \cdot k + 23$ you like, and you will be talking about the same element, which is unique.

The key is therefore also unique - your key is an element of a multiplicative group, which can be written in many ways ($160 \cdot k + 23$, where $k$ is in $Z$)

Comment: Please note that the OP got the order wrong, the multiplicative order is $\lambda(n)=\operatorname{lcm}(16,10)=80$ and not $160$ which means $23\equiv 103\equiv 183$ as exponents.

Comment: Thanks! I haven't noticed that - just blindly copied OP's numbers!

Comment: @ValentynKuznietsov OK, I understand that i can write $d$ in different ways that are represent the same element in the multiplicative group. But the attacker that tries to brute-force the private key, can't just find one value that represents the same private key in the multiplicative group?

Comment: It does not make his work any easier. Between 0 and 79 (for group mod 80) there is only one such element. Other 'representations' will be bigger than 80 - how that makes bruteforce easier?

Comment: And maybe it was not exactly your question, I would also like to point out that this bruteforce is assumed to be hard. If he tries to brute d directly, he needs to solve Discrete Log Problem. If he tries to factorize your n to be able to calculate d by taking modular inverse of e, he  needs to solve Factorization problem, which has equal difficulty as Discrete Log Problem. (assumed to be very hard)